# Building brick moulding in cold weather

Tags: caulking

It's almost winter and I still have a pending brick moulding job I need to do. According to the weather forecast, the maximum temperature that I'll likely see in the coming few days is around 8 degrees Celsius. Questions:

1. Should I worry about the brick moulding lumber warping in summer since I'm going to cut it based on its size in cold weather? It's finger-jointed tough wood.
2. Should I worry about caulking not curing properly due to the cold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the lengths of brick mold are usually fairly short, less than 7 feet usually, expansion or contraction of a wood product is negligible. We often install exterior trim in cold temps here in Maine and really never see a problem. A couple of tips that will help insure tight joints year round are to put some waterproof wood glue, like titebond III on all the joint faces and be sure to put a finish nail through the joint. Use a good quality siliconized, paintable acrylic caulk. This product will set up fine in cold weather as long as you are not sub-zero. Temp specs are usually on the product, but don't be afraid to push it a bit, won't really matter. Also there is now low temp exterior paints available.  Good luck